# Update value on 2nd line of row if another entry has been made

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have a code whereby it works fine for when it finds the Staff ID for 1st Job allocated then it will update timestamp on the same line in column "M" when list has been selected from list box however when i try to update the new line of row for the same person with different Job number it will still again update first Job line of row and not the 2nd Job line of row.

```
me.lstselector.list(x,3) - it is the Staff ID in column G
me.lstselector.list(x,2) - it is the Job number in column F
```

i need code to find using Job number and staff ID, when matches it both then to updates time on same row every time in column M

here its the code

```
Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="1234"
   lCol = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 3)
    Set findvalue = Sheet1.Range("G:G").Find(What:=lCol, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -2)
     findvalue.Offset(0, 8).Value = Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to continue searching until JobNo column matches.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

    Dim sID As String, sJobNo As String, rng As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    sID = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 3)
    sJobNo = Me.lstselector.list(x,2)

    With Sheet1.Range("G:G")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=sID, LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' rng is col G
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rng.Address
            Do
                If rng.Offset(0, -1) = sJobNo Then ' col F
                    rng.Offset(0, 6) = Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS") ' col M
                    'Debug.Print rng.Address
                End If
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
            Loop While rng.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```